# Retrieving all data from database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have encountered a problem while I was developing my Android application.  I am trying to retrieve all the data from my Android application, but I don't exactly know how.  Here is my DBAdapter.java class:

```
package com.example.foodsaver2;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.AvoidXfermode;
import android.util.Log;
import com.example.*;

public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "rowid";
public static final String KEY_CUSTOMER = "customer";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS1 = "address1";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS2 = "address2";
public static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
public static final String KEY_STATE = "state";
public static final String KEY_ZIP = "zipCode";
public static final String KEY_SEARCH = "searchData";
public static final String TOTAL_CARB = "carb";
public static final String FIBER = "fiber";
public static final String SUGAR = "sugar";
public static final String PROTEIN = "protein";
public static final String SODIUM = "salt";
public static final String TOTALCALORIES = "calories";
public static Context contextOfApplication;



private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
public SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Data";
private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "Info";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 =
        "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " USING fts3(" +
                KEY_CUSTOMER + /*"INTEGER," + */ "," +
                KEY_NAME + "," +
                KEY_ADDRESS1 + "," +
                KEY_ADDRESS2 + "," +
                KEY_CITY + "," +
                KEY_STATE + "," +
                KEY_ZIP + "," +
                KEY_SEARCH + "," +
                TOTAL_CARB + "," +
                FIBER + "," +
                SUGAR + "," +
                PROTEIN + "," +
                SODIUM + "," +
                TOTALCALORIES + "," +
                " UNIQUE (" + KEY_CUSTOMER + "));";

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE1);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE1);

    }
    public static Context getContextOfApplication(){
        return contextOfApplication;

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}


public long createCustomer(String customer, String name, String address1, String address2, String city, String state, String zipCode, String carb, String fiber, String sugar, String protein, String sodium, String calories) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    String searchValue =     customer + " " +
            name + " " +
            address1 + " " +
            city + " " +
            state + " " +
            zipCode;
    initialValues.put(KEY_CUSTOMER, customer);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS1, address1);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS2, address2);
    initialValues.put(KEY_CITY, city);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STATE, state);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ZIP, zipCode);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SEARCH, searchValue);
    initialValues.put(TOTAL_CARB, carb);
    initialValues.put(FIBER, fiber);
    initialValues.put(SUGAR, sugar);
    initialValues.put(PROTEIN, protein);
    initialValues.put(SODIUM, sodium);
    initialValues.put(TOTALCALORIES, calories);

    return mDb.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);

}


public Cursor searchCustomer(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    String query = "SELECT docid as _id," +
            KEY_CUSTOMER + "," +
            KEY_NAME + "," +
            "(" + KEY_ADDRESS1 + "||" +
            "(case when " + KEY_ADDRESS2 +  "> '' then '\n' || " + KEY_ADDRESS2 + " else '' end)) as " +  KEY_ADDRESS +"," +
            KEY_ADDRESS1 + "," +
            KEY_ADDRESS2 + "," +
            KEY_CITY + "," +
            KEY_STATE + "," +
            KEY_ZIP + "," +
            TOTAL_CARB + "," +
            FIBER + "," +
            SUGAR + "," +
            PROTEIN + "," +
            SODIUM + "," +
            TOTALCALORIES +
            " from " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
            " where " +  KEY_SEARCH + " MATCH '" + inputText + "';";
    Log.w(TAG, query);
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(query,null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;

}


public boolean deleteAllCustomers() {

    int doneDelete = 0;
    doneDelete = mDb.delete(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null , null);
    Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
    return doneDelete > 0;

}
}
```

Here is my SendFeedback.java class, where I try to retrieve the data.

```
package com.example.foodsaver2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

 /**
 * Created by mother on 2/7/14.
 */
public class SendFeedback extends Activity {
private DBAdapter mDbHelper;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.send_feedback);
    mDbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
}
public void send (View v) {
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.getData();
    GmailSender sender = new GmailSender("omitted for privacy", "omitted for privacy");
    try {
    sender.sendMail("This is Subject",
            "This is Body",
            "omitted for privacy",
            "omitted for privacy");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot send message!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
}
```

I don't know how to do this.  I have searched the internet and SO for a while, but I can't find a solution.  I don't have any experience with SQLiteDatabases either.  Any help regarding this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial on sqlite databases on android:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

take a look a this extract:

```
public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
        comments.add(comment);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return comments;
}
```

And

```
private Comment cursorToComment(Cursor cursor) {
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
    comment.setComment(cursor.getString(1));
    return comment;
}
```

so for your app you could have:

public List getAllComments() {
        List customers = new ArrayList();

```
    Cursor cursor = database.query(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, new String[]{"KEY_CUSTOMER", "KEY_NAME " , etc..}, null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Customer customer = cursorToCustomer(cursor);
        customers.add(comment);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return customers;
}
```

And

```
private Customer cursorToCustomer(Cursor cursor) {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setCustomer(cursor.getString(0));
    customer.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    customer.setAddress1(cursor.getString(2));
    customer.setAddress2(cursor.getString(3));
    customer.setCity(cursor.getString(4));
    customer.setState(cursor.getString(5));
    customer.setZipCode(cursor.getString(6));
    customer.setSearchValue(cursor.getString(7));
    customer.setCarb(cursor.getString(8));
    customer.setFiber(cursor.getString(9));
    customer.setSugar(cursor.getString(10));
    customer.setProtein(cursor.getString(11));
    customer.setSodium(cursor.getString(12));
    customer.setCalories(cursor.getString(13));

    return comment;
}
```

PS: You need to create your own class "Customer" to hold the data shown here

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where to put these exercepts in my application?

Comment: Where you have your deleteAllCustomers(), searchCustomer(String inputText) etc...

In my example i use an example class Comment to show you how to do it.. you need to change the values of the cursor and all to fit your application

Comment: I Edited my answer, hope it's enough

Btw the link on the beginning of my answer is a pretty comprehensive on databases in android.. if you are not at ease with it you should definitely read it, it might save you some headaches in the future.. 

Ad you should consider separating the DatabaseHelper from the datasource, it's much cleaner

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as answered with the checkmark on the left